# ease out and in while spinning on hover css

Tags: html, css

My css:

```css
.App-logo {
  animation: rotating infinite 10s linear;
  height: 40vmin;
}

.App-logo:hover {
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 100;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}


@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

It should slow down on hover and get speed without hovering but what it does a little off i wanted it to do
[image]
I think the problem that i don't actually know how to save a state of the keyframe and apply it to another animation to ease out and then in, but this just an assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't able to save keyframe states using only CSS to transition between them, unfortunately. If you want to transition between them, you'd need to use something like Javascript to track states and manipulate data at any point in time.